# the file is not owned by hive and load data is also not ran as hive

Tags: hive, sqoop

I use HDP3.1. And I Ambari to deploy hadoop cluster and hive. I want to use only one user(hdfs) to run the all programs(such as hadoop, hive, sqoop, yarn...). So I change the users all to hdfs in set ACCOUNTS step when deploy hadoop cluster in ambari. After deployed, I run sqoop to import data from mysql to hive. I have the following issue.

```
19/02/20 18:44:13 INFO hive.HiveImport: ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Load Data failed for hdfs://datacenter1:8020/user/hdfs/person/part-m-00000 as the file is not owned by hive and load data is also not ran as hive
19/02/20 18:44:13 INFO hive.HiveImport: INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hdfs_20190220184412_d61d8591-04fc-41a7-b412-d64935ddd046); Time taken: 0.235 seconds
19/02/20 18:44:13 INFO hive.HiveImport: Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Load Data failed for hdfs://datacenter1:8020/user/hdfs/person/part-m-00000 as the file is not owned by hive and load data is also not ran as hive (state=08S01,code=1)
19/02/20 18:44:13 INFO hive.HiveImport: Closing: 0: jdbc:hive2://datacenter2:2181,datacenter1:2181,datacenter3:2181/default;password=hdfs;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;user=hdfs;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2
19/02/20 18:44:13 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: Hive exited with status 2
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeExternalHiveScript(HiveImport.java:299)
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:558)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:656)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:186)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:240)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:249)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:258)
```

This issue happened in reduce step. I don't why it need hive user. Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

change config of hive in hive-site.xml.
Change value: hive.load.data.owner from hive to nifi.
Restart all hive service and check again.
Duonghb